# PhoneGap Eclipse Issue - eglCodecCommon glUtilsParamSize: unknow param errors

Tags: android, cordova

I have just started on phonegap and trying to setup first basic minimal project in eclipse. I followed through the phonegap docs at http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide

but I am getting continuous errors like these. Any pointer to fix this would be helpful. thx

```
03-12 06:08:05.970: E/eglCodecCommon(825): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
03-12 06:08:05.980: E/eglCodecCommon(825): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
03-12 06:08:06.080: I/chromium(825): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
03-12 06:08:06.280: I/chromium(825): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
03-12 06:08:06.660: E/eglCodecCommon(825): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
03-12 06:08:06.660: E/eglCodecCommon(825): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
03-12 06:08:06.720: E/eglCodecCommon(825): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
03-12 06:08:06.720: E/eglCodecCommon(825): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
03-12 06:08:06.760: E/eglCodecCommon(825): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
03-12 06:08:06.760: E/eglCodecCommon(825): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
03-12 06:08:06.800: E/eglCodecCommon(825): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
03-12 06:08:06.810: E/eglCodecCommon(825): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
03-12 06:08:06.870: E/eglCodecCommon(825): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
03-12 06:08:06.870: E/eglCodecCommon(825): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
03-12 06:08:06.890: E/eglCodecCommon(825): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
03-12 06:08:06.890: E/eglCodecCommon(825): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
03-12 06:08:06.930: E/eglCodecCommon(825): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
03-12 06:08:06.940: E/eglCodecCommon(825): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
03-12 06:08:06.960: E/eglCodecCommon(825): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
03-12 06:08:06.980: E/eglCodecCommon(825): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
03-12 06:08:07.180: E/eglCodecCommon(825): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
03-12 06:08:07.180: E/eglCodecCommon(825): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
03-12 06:08:07.210: E/eglCodecCommon(825): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
03-12 06:08:07.240: E/eglCodecCommon(825): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
03-12 06:08:07.320: E/eglCodecCommon(825): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
03-12 06:08:07.320: E/eglCodecCommon(825): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
```

Comment: Where are you seeing those errors? If it's in logcat, they may not even be about your app. You get messages about anything runing in your device.

Comment: Its logcat msgs. But I dont see similar message when I run non phonegap applications like a android app. Issue is that it is an infinite loop and doesn;t stop.

Comment: I have given up with phonegap, not worth time and nothing interesting. Will stick to native for now..

Comment: @Amit, this is not specific to PhoneGap, it is specific to the GPU emulation of the Android emulator.

Comment: @Amit It is not specific to Android. It is something related to the Emulator using Laptops graphics processor. Just a tiny little error that is specific to Lollipop...

Answer (score 139):

This is caused if you use the "Use host GPU" setting of the emulator and it will disappear after you uncheck this option. If you still need "Use host GPU", you can just filter out the errors by customizing the Logcat Filter. Enter `^(?!eglCodecCommon)` into the "by Log Tag (regex)" field in order to strip out the unwanted lines from the Logcat output.

Comment: If you're wondering how to customize the logcat filter in android studio: There's a drop down list on the right-hand side of logcat with your package name. Click on that and then `edit filter configuration`.

Comment: I noticed it needed to formatted like this in Xamarin Studio. tag:^(?!(eglCodecCommon))

Comment: Make sure you do this in the *Log Tag* otherwise you'll see partial results

Comment: Does this happen the only Emulator?

Comment: This regex doesn't work for me

Answer (score 71):

This is an error that you see when your emulator has the "Use host GPU" setting checked. If you uncheck it then the error goes away. Of course, then your emulator is not as responsive anymore.

Comment: My KitKat emulator won't even start up if I don't check "Use host GPU"

Comment: Yes, Emulator does not start if "Use host GPU" is on

Comment: The emulators are horribly inconsistent and constantly being updated. New features and flaws seem to come with every update. It's funny because I had been using the Android SDK Build Tools: 19.0.1 when I posted the comment. Back then I had to uncheck use host GPU or I'd get the error described above. Now I was forced by update to use the Android SDK Build Tools: 19.1.0 and the emulator won't start unless I check Use host GPU.

Comment: I have 2 project (both native android java projects, not PhoneGap), and I run them in the same emulator. One of them has the logcat full of these, the other has none... Any idea?

Answer (score 15):

For those who like to work close to the metal, here is a command that will clear out the unwanted soot, without needing any special tools or scripts:

```
adb logcat "eglCodecCommon:S"
```

Answer (score 7):

@theczechsensation's solution is already half way there.

For those who like to exclude noisy log messages **and** keep the log to their app only this is the solution:

[image: New Logcat Filter Settings]

Add your exclusions to **Log Tag** like this: *^(?!(eglCodecCommon|tagToExclude))*

Add your package name or prefix to **Package Name**: *com.mycompany.*

This way it is possible to filter for as many strings you like **and** keep the log to your package.

Answer (score 2):

I Get the same message, when using Intel XHAM emulator (instead of ARM) and have  "Use Host GPU" option enabled. I belive when you disable it, it goes away.

Answer (score 1):

It's very annoying. I'm not sure why Google places it there - no one needs these trash from emulator at all; we know what we are doing. I'm using `pidcat` and I modified it a bit

`BUG_LINE  = re.compile(r'.*nativeGetEnabledTags.*')
BUG_LINE2  = re.compile(r'.*glUtilsParamSize.*')
BUG_LINE3  = re.compile(r'.*glSizeof.*')`

and

  `bug_line = BUG_LINE.match(line)
  if bug_line is not None:
    continue
  bug_line2 = BUG_LINE2.match(line)
  if bug_line2 is not None:
    continue
  bug_line3 = BUG_LINE3.match(line)
  if bug_line3 is not None:
    continue`

It's an ugly fix and if you're using the real device you may need those OpenGL errors, but you got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Big surprise, you scrolled all this way down, because all the above answers don't work anymore, why? Apparently Android Studio recently decided to drop the regex support in logcat.

Use `-tag:UnWantedTag` to exclude a tag instead. Use several to exclude more.

Like.. `-tag:eglCodecCommon -tag:chatty`

You are welcome..