# Unable to simulate location data in Android emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, geolocation, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to test my app, which uses geolocation using the emulator. Several methods are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator). I'm going to `Window->Open Perspective->DDMS`, then entering lat. and long. one in `Location Controls` and then I hit "Send".

[image]

But it doesn't work. Instead I see the following error: `Unable to send command to the emulator.`

Why is this happening!?

I don't think my app is the problem because I tested with the emulator's default browser and it also cannot access location info.

Details:

- OSX 10.9.4
- AVD_for_Nexus_4_by_Google targeting v4.4.2
- Eclipse IDE for Android Developers    23.0.2.1259578

**Update:**
I changed to `AVD_for_Galaxy_Nexus_by_Google` and it still doesn't work, but I no longer see that error. I click send and nothing happens.

**Update2:**
I've tested using Telnet to pass location data to the emulator, and again nothing happens. No errors. Just nothing. Urgh!

```
telnet localhost 5554
geo fix 50 50
```

It responds with `OK` but nothing happens. Still no location data available.

**Update3:**
I notice a stream of the following errors in LogCat

```
09-20 17:58:59.910: E/eglCodecCommon(1777): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
09-20 17:58:59.910: E/eglCodecCommon(1777): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
09-20 17:58:59.930: E/eglCodecCommon(1777): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
```

The app seems to be running fine, and these errors are supposedly explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22348801/phonegap-eclipse-issue-eglcodeccommon-glutilsparamsize-unknow-param-errors).

**Update 4:**
I've seen multiple suggestions to confirm that my AVD has GPS Support enabled, but this option/setting does not appear anywhere. When I open the "Android Virtual Device Manager" and then click "Edit" on one of my devices, this is what I see:
[image]

No mention of "GPS Support".

**Update 5:**
I checked the config.ini file for all my AVDs and they are all correctly set to `hw.gps=yes`. I also created an AVD using a Google API target, however I'm still having the same problem. The app loads but no location data is available, with "Location Controls" as well as telnet.

**Update 6:**
Following Gyebro's suggestions below... trying to load his LocationDemo app...
[image]

Here's what I see in the LogCat:

Comment: Does `yourLocationClient.getLastLocation()` return with `null`? Are you implementing `LocationListener`? Could anything interfere with your emulator port (5554)? Have you tried Android Studio (and its Android Device Monitor)?

Comment: There is no location listener. As for `yourLocatoinClient`, I'm very new to Android development so I'm not sure what that is. If you give me instructions I'll test. I haven't tried Android Studio but I tried with Genymotion plugin and it STILL didn't work.

Comment: Just check if your AVD has these settings: AVD -> Hardware -> New -> GPS support -> "Yes"

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal I'm not seeing that option. From Eclipse I open the "Android Virtual Device Manager" and it shows a list of AVDs but "GPS Support" field.

Comment: *no "GPS Support" field

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal please see **Update 5** above.

Answer (score 6):

To check whether your emulator supports GPS, go to `~/.android/avd/<emulatorname>.avd/` and check `config.ini` and `hardware-qemu.ini` (if exists) they should contain:

> hw.gps = yes

**EDIT**
You must use a Google APIs system image. You should set `Google APIs - API Level 1#` as target

[image]
**End of EDIT**

Assuming this is so, and Location is enabled in your emulator, run this test application in your emulator: [LocationTest demo](https://github.com/Gyebro/android-demos/tree/master/LocationTest), for details see the [Dev docs on Retrieving the Current Location](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

This sample implements `GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks`, `GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener` and `LocationListener`. And also checks for Google Play Services before connecting with the LocationClient (that's why we needed a **Google** Emulator image.) (See [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/Gyebro/android-demos/blob/master/LocationTest/app/src/main/java/com/gyebro/locationtest/MainActivity.java))

After you start the app, you should see the Location icon in the status bar. Also verify, that the GP Services are present and the LocationClient is connected in the Log.

[image]

```
 D/LocationTest﹕ Google Play services is available.
 D/LocationTest﹕ LocationClient: Connected
```

After sending `geo fix 66 80` using telnet (should respond with `OK`) or other *valid* coordinates using DDMS, you should see:

[image]

```
 D/LocationTest﹕ Location changed!
```

If you are still lost with this approach, another way to simulate locations is to [create a Mock Location Provider app](https://developer.android.com/training/location/location-testing.html).

Comment: Thanks. I checked the config.ini file for all my AVDs and they are all correctly set to `hw.gps=yes`. See my **Update 5** above. I'm slow working with Eclipse, so I haven't tried the Location Test yet... but I'm not sure what it's testing for. I know GPS is unavailable because I can use the default internet browser to visit a page which requests geolocation data and it doesn't work. Should I still proceed with the Location Test?

Comment: @SDP I definitely suggest to try that little demo app (only a single activity, plus some permissions in the AndroidManifest). I've tried http://html5demos.com/geo with the Emulator's browser and it does not work. (Maybe it reads the last location. No location icon appears in the status bar)

Comment: @SDP After I've requested location update with the test app, html5demos.com/geo manages to get the location. (However it does not request location update itself.)

Comment: That's interesting! In my quest to figure this out I've heard other stories about geolocations not working until something else triggered them. I'll try the app asap.

Comment: @SDP I hope you will succeed!

Comment: I'm working on it now, but I'm having trouble finding documentation to get the testing app onto an AVD.

Comment: I found the error from style.xml: `Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'. styles.xml /MainActivity/res/values line 4 Android AAPT Problem
`

Comment: I finally got the app to run, but it doesn't work. See my **Update 6** above. I don't see any errors in the LogCat.

Comment: @SDP Alternatively, you might try Android Studio Beta (based on the awesome IntelliJ), because I made the demo project in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61913/discussion-between-gyebro-and-sdp).

Answer (score 2):

You really should use **GENYMOTION** it offers a GPS feature in which u set the location coordinates, plus it's faster than the default emulator and works fine in almost every OS, heres the Docus on how to apply that GPS stuff [here](https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/doc/) inside that page look for "GPS widget". Good luck.

Heres a shot from that window

[image: genymotino gps widget]

Answer (score 1):

I tried with latest SDK and adb tools, i see the same problem with Google Maps and web browser based location (maps.google.com). I used adb command line as well as telnet methods to set the location. Also verified my .avd file has `hw.gps=yes` (which is set by default). I even tried with older Google API images. I made sure to try out different accuracy levels too - device only, high accuracy etc. I notice lot of graphics rendering issues and quite a few opengl error messages in logcat, similar to ones you see.

I did get google maps app to work on Android emulator using mock locations feature. You can use mock locations on a real device too, which i prefer for its performance. For details on [how to use mock location please see this.](http://developer.android.com/training/location/location-testing.html). Download the zip file which has LocationProvider project , that lets you simulate different location and movement scenarios.

so you can pick:

- Use a physical android device with mock locations feature
- If you want to use emulator, try with mock locations
- I had success with genymotion too, you can set any location you want from command line `genyshell` that comes with genymotion

  `genyshell.exe -c "gps setstatus enabled"
   genyshell.exe -c "gps setlatitude 30.3077609"
   genyshell.exe -c "gps setlongitude -97.7534014"`

device is preferable for performance reasons.

**Update:**
I tested with [LocationTest demo by gyebro](https://github.com/Gyebro/android-demos/tree/master/LocationTest) and it works when i set the location params using telnet. So the problem seems to be with google maps or browser and not with emulator or adb tools.
[image: location test demo]

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried with free version of [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/)? It works as a real device connected by USB, and it can create GPS positions as you need. I know that this is not a solution for your AVD problem but AVD is in generally a poor solution to Android testing on emulators.

**It's free if you want to test this function specifically.**

Comment: I did try with the free version of Genymotion, but it also didn't work even after I set the GPS location using the button. I appreciate the suggestion, but it's not actually an answer to the question I asked so it probably belongs in a discussion elsewhere.

Comment: Well, genymotion is an awesome emulator. it is a shame it didn't work

Comment: Genymotion is not longer free!

Answer (score 0):

I was running through the same errors. The problem was that the AVD DDMS uses a comma instead of a dot in their location coordinates.

Use LAT: -16,691534 LNG: -49,266185 something like this and you will be fine!