# Testing Google Play Services AdMob on AVD various errors

Tags: android, admob

This expands on my question from here which shows the code of my program

[Android AdMob addTestDevice not getting deviceID in logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26170462/android-admob-addtestdevice-not-getting-deviceid-in-logcat)

I want to test the AdMob service on AVD and I read that I must use either Google APIs 17, 18, 19 ( I tried all as the target) to test it. I get various issues depending on the API version

1.On Google API 16. The test Ad banner does not seem to load even though log cat says Ad Finished Loading. When I rotate the ad appears. That is portrait to landscape

2.On Google API 16.  "Google Play Services are out of date" , "Google Play Services not available due to error 2". I implemented the check about checking the Google play version. The code of this is in the link. The dialog appears saying update services however clicking update seems to cause the dialog to just appear again and not do anything. Im not sure if this is because its AVD or would it happen on a real device?

3. On Google API 19, I get the error on logcat, "The Google Play Services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included". This is one is weird because the test banner shows  in either portrait or landscape as well as no out of date GPS dialog.
4. On Google API 19. Log cat also keeps reporting as error countless time .

   10-03 08:07:12.238: E/eglCodecCommon(1179): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
   10-03 08:07:12.278: E/eglCodecCommon(1179): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)

If more code needs to be posted or my AVD info, please let me know. Im using Eclipse ADT

Answer (score 0):

Hi to test on emulators use this code snipet.

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)    // remove if in real time use
        .build();
```

Comment: I have added this line already. Please see the link above which shows the code.