# Error when creating text input field

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, android-virtual-device

I am incorporating jQuery Mobile to my web application for Android. In the application I have created a simple text input box.  The build process went fine and when I run my app in the emulator, everything loads fine.

The problem is every time I click or focus on the text input box, lots of error messages (more than 50 rows) showing up in the LogCat console.

Sample of the error message:

```
01-30 23:11:16.497: E/eglCodecCommon(1501): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
01-30 23:11:16.779: E/eglCodecCommon(1501): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
01-30 23:11:16.970: E/eglCodecCommon(1501): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
01-30 23:11:17.168: E/eglCodecCommon(1501): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
01-30 23:11:17.485: E/eglCodecCommon(1501): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
01-30 23:11:17.678: E/eglCodecCommon(1501): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
```

My HTML are as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Android Hybrid Test</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Android Hybrid Test</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content" class="ui-content">
            <form>
                <div class="ui-field-contain">
                    <label for="origin">Origin:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="origin" id="origin">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="map">
        <div id="map-canvas" style="float:right;width:70%;height:100%;"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
</body>
```

Any insight on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to find that Host GPU option on the emulator but could not find out on the emulator that I use.  I am using Genymotion emulator and the solution in my case is that I need to set the "hardware accelerated" value to false in AndroidManifest.xml.  Thank you for your input, it will be useful if someone is using the default Android ADB.

Answer (score 0):

Google?
[PhoneGap Eclipse Issue - eglCodecCommon glUtilsParamSize: unknow param errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22348801/phonegap-eclipse-issue-eglcodeccommon-glutilsparamsize-unknow-param-errors)

> This is an error that you see when your emulator has the "Use host
>   GPU" setting checked. If you uncheck it then the error goes away. Of
>   course, then your emulator is not as responsive anymore.