# How to solve "glUtilsParamSize" problems

Tags: java, android, webview

I have `WebView` in my android app. After I start the emulator I saw many red lines that repeat lines below:

```
1656-1656/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
1656-1656/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/eglCodecCommon﹕ **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
1656-1656/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
1656-1656/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
1656-1656/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/eglCodecCommon﹕ **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
1656-1656/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
1656-1656/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
1656-1656/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/eglCodecCommon﹕ **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PhoneGap Eclipse Issue - eglCodecCommon glUtilsParamSize: unknow param errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22348801/phonegap-eclipse-issue-eglcodeccommon-glutilsparamsize-unknow-param-errors)

Answer (score 2):

Easily solvable. This way you can exclude noisy log messages **and** keep the log to their app only. Wonderfully extendable with new log tags to suppress.

Add your exclusions to **Log Tag** like this: *^(?!(eglCodecCommon|tagToExclude))*

Add your package name or prefix to **Package Name**: *com.mycompany.*

This way it is possible to filter for as many strings you like **and** keep the log to your package.

[image: New Logcat Filter Settings]

Comment: not answering the question