# Android webview has an error

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-webview

I Created a simple webview app and I receive this error:

> 03-19 13:17:39.493    4206-4250/com.example.qala.mohamad_bilal E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
>   03-19 13:17:39.504    4206-4250/com.example.qala.mohamad_bilal E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
>   03-19 13:17:39.513    4206-4250/com.example.qala.mohamad_bilal E/eglCodecCommon﹕ **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)

and here's the code:

```
view1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
view1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
view1.loadUrl("10.0.2.2:8888/epoints/");
view1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22348801/phonegap-eclipse-issue-eglcodeccommon-glutilsparamsize-unknow-param-errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has something to do with the emulator and your host GPU. I wouldn't worry about it too much, a lot of people get those errors. You can always try it on an actual device and see if you still get those errors.