# Xamarin.Forms - Problem creating Android Wear Application

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

When running the tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/android/wear/get-started/hello-wear?tabs=windows#feedback
example on Visual Studio to build an Android Wear application - I get the below errors:

02-13 20:13:24.035 E/eglCodecCommon( 9352): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
02-13 20:13:24.035 E/eglCodecCommon( 9352): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da

I am running this using Android 9.0 API 28 and using an AndroidWear (Round) emulator. 
For my IDE I am using Visual Studio 2019 V16.4.5

Can anyone advise a workaround as this is a Uni Project so just need to create a simple demo application with a couple buttons and using some Xamarin Widgets etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search this error message, you can easily find the answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22348801/phonegap-eclipse-issue-eglcodeccommon-glutilsparamsize-unknow-param-errors):

> This is caused if you use the "Use host GPU" setting of the emulator
>   and it will disappear after you uncheck this option.

It is specific to the GPU emulation of the Android emulator.

So you can edit the `gpu.mode` when you create a Android wear round emulator to get rid of the error. There are also descriptions of each option at the right side:

[image]